# ZXing.net throws System.ArgumentException: Font 'Arial' does not support style 'Regular' error

Tags: c#, fonts

When executing an asp.net page which creates barcodes using ZXing.net, it works fine on Windows 10 computers but not on windows 2012 server. On the server the following error is thrown.

The code:

```
        Image imgBarCode = new Image();
                var codabar = new ZXing.BarcodeWriter();
                codabar.Options = options;
                codabar.Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128;
                using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(codabar.Write(customerID.Trim())))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
                        imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                    }

                    panelGeneralInfo.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);

                }
```

The type initializer for 'ZXing.Rendering.BitmapRenderer' threw an exception.

```
System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> 
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'ZXing.Rendering.BitmapRenderer' threw an exception. ---> 
System.ArgumentException: Font 'Arial' does not support style 'Regular'.
at System.Drawing.Font.CreateNativeFont()
at System.Drawing.Font.Initialize(FontFamily family, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet, Boolean gdiVerticalFont)
at System.Drawing.Font.Initialize(String familyName, Single emSize, FontStyle style, GraphicsUnit unit, Byte gdiCharSet, Boolean gdiVerticalFont)
at System.Drawing.Font..ctor(String familyName, Single emSize, FontStyle style)
at ZXing.Rendering.BitmapRenderer..cctor() in C:\ZXing.Net.0.14.0.0\Source\lib\renderer\BitmapRenderer.cs:line 56 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at ZXing.Rendering.BitmapRenderer..ctor() in C:\ZXing.Net.0.14.0.0\Source\lib\renderer\BitmapRenderer.cs:line 65
at ZXing.BarcodeWriter..ctor() in C:\ZXing.Net.0.14.0.0\Source\lib\BarcodeWriter.cs:line 112
```

Comment: Remember to show your (reduced) code, too, so that people can understand what you're doing. There's not going to be a lot of useful things to say about *just* a stack trace, and explain what you have considered but were able to rule out already through your own debugging efforts.

Comment: Updated the question with code. Thanks

Comment: this does not look like the code involved in the stacktrace, can you explain what part of the code you're showing maps to which line indicated in the stack trace?

Comment: This line is causing the error: using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(codabar.Write(customerID.Trim()))) The BarCodeWriter internally uses BitMapRenderer.

Comment: No, please: indicate how these things link up in your post, so that people can understand what the problem is and where from reading your post rather than the comments. Also note that the line you point at has nothing to do with Fonts, so you probably need to show what's going on *inside* the calls on that line, because none of the code you show involves the `Arial` font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting IIS resolved the issue. Obviously the stack trace created by .net framework is kind of misleading!